# Can we use @Configuration annotation which can only load based on application.properties attributes?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a property in my application.properties file that says as below.

```
region = local;
```

I have a class LoadConfiguration.java like below.

```
@Configuration
public class LoadConfiguration {
 @Bean
 public ....
 .....
}
```

I want spring to load the configuration only if the region is not local. How can I achieve such functionality?

Comment: @Pushpak consider using profiles as `@Profile` supports negation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

> @ConditionalOnExpression("'${region}' != 'local'")

Answer (score 1):

There is a `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation, but this annotation only allows you to load the configuration if the property matches. So this can't be used if you want to load the configuration if the property does not match.

The easiest solution would be to work with Spring profiles. This can be achieved by using the `spring.profiles.active` property:

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

And then you can use the `@Profile` annotation to only load your configuration if the profile isn't local:

```java
@Profile("!local") // Add this
@Configuration
public class NotLocalConfiguration {
    // Only loaded when profile is not local
}
```

---

If you really want to work with the `region` property, you can implement your own conditional. This can be achieved by writing a class that implements `Condition`:

```java
public class NotLocalCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return !"local".equals(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("region"));
    }
}
```

And then you can apply it by using the following anotation:

```java
@Conditional(NotLocalCondition.class) // Add this
@Configuration
public class NotLocalConfiguration {
    // Only loaded when profile is not local
}
```